# Don't understand proof of why $\cos x$ is a contraction mapping on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

I've read a couple proofs of why $\cos x$ is a contraction mapping on $[0,1]$ but none of them are clear enough for me to understand. What if we have something like $\lvert \cos x - \cos y \rvert = w > \lvert x - y \rvert = w - \epsilon$? Then we can not multiply the right side of the inequality by a real number that is $< 1$ to get $k \cdot (w - \epsilon) \geq w$.

I am also having trouble getting an intuitive feel of the behavior of $\lvert \cos x - \cos y \rvert$ as $\lvert x - y \rvert$ increases or decreases in value. I cannot make a direct relationship to whether the value of $\lvert \cos x - \cos y \rvert$ will increase or decrease as $\lvert x - y \rvert$ increases or decreases.

Comment: Which proofs have you read that aren't clear enough?  Sharing more context may prevent people from repeating the stuff that isn't clear to you, and allow them to help clarify.

Comment: "What if"...but does this happen?

Comment: You can use MVT, noting that $\sin(x) < 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that $f: A \mapsto B$ is a contraction mapping if for all $x,y \in A$, there exists $k \in [0,1)$ independent of $x$ and $y$ such that
$$d_B(f(x),f(y)) \leq k d_A(x,y)$$
In your case, I assume $d_B(\cdot,\cdot) = d_A(\cdot,\cdot) = \vert \cdot - \cdot \vert$. The set $A = [0,1]$ and $B = [\cos(1),1]$. We have
$$\cos(x)-\cos(y) = -2\sin((x-y)/2)\sin((x+y)/2)$$
Hence, we obtain
\begin{align}
\vert \cos(x)-\cos(y) \vert & = \vert -2\sin((x-y)/2)\sin((x+y)/2) \vert = \vert -2 \vert \cdot \vert \sin((x-y)/2) \vert \cdot \vert \sin((x+y)/2)\vert\\
& \leq 2 \cdot \vert (x-y)/2 \vert \cdot \sin(1) = \sin(1) \vert x-y \vert \,\,\,\,\,\, (\spadesuit)
\end{align}
where we made use of the fact that $\sin(u)$ is increasing on $[0,1]$ and $\vert \sin(v) \vert \leq v$. Hence, from $(\spadesuit)$, we obtain
$$\vert \cos(x)-\cos(y) \vert \leq \sin(1) \vert x- y \vert$$
Hence, this is a contraction mapping with $k= \sin(1) < 1$.

Comment: To fix it, note $(x+y)/2 \in [0,1]$, so the sine of that is in $[0,\sin(1)]$ and $\sin(1)<1$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Fixed.