# Recursive sequence defined using $\cos x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ , the sequence $\{a_n\}$ , where $a_1=x$ and   $a_{n+1}=\cos (a_n)$ for all $n$ is convergent . True/False

I think this is true. Well , my plan is to show $\cos x$ is a contractive mapping on the real line (complete metric space) and then the above sequence would converge to the unique fixed point of $\cos x$ by Banach Fixed Point Theorem.

But I am facing a little problem :

$|\cos x-\cos y|=2|\sin \big( \frac {x+y}2\big)||\sin \big( \frac {x-y}2\big)|$

using $|\sin x| \le |x|$ and $|\sin x|\le 1$

$\Rightarrow |\cos x-\cos y| \le |x-y|$ which doesn't fit the definition of contractive mapping.

Any way to tackle this.? Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141325/showing-that-cosx-is-a-contraction-mapping-on-0-pi?r=SearchResults, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248626/dont-understand-proof-of-why-cos-x-is-a-contraction-mapping-on-0-1?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

**Claim 1: $g(x) = \cos x - x$ has a unique solution $x^*$ and $x^* \in [\cos 1, 1]$**

*Proof:* $g$ is strictly decreasing on $\mathbb R$, $g(0) = 1 > 0$ and $g\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) =-\frac{\pi}{2} < 0$.

**Claim 2: $u_2 \in [\cos 1, 1]$**

*Proof: You have $u_1 \in [-1,1]$, $\cos x$ is even and therefore $\cos [[-1,1]] = \cos [[0,1]] = [\cos 1, 1]$ as $\cos x$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\pi]$.*

**Claim 3: $\cos x$ is a contracting map from $[\cos 1, 1]$ to $[\cos 1,1]$**

*Proof: follows from the facts that $\cos x$ is strictly decreasing on $[\cos 1, 1]$ and $\cos (\cos 1) < 1$.*

Recall that for a strictly decreasing map $f[[a,b]] = [f(b),f(a)]$.

Comment: So are you saying $\cos x$  is contractive on $[0,1] $ ?

Comment: I'm saying that $\cos x$ is contractive on $[a_2,1]$.

Comment: $\cos(x)$ *is* contractive on $[0, 1]$ (even on $[-1, 1]$) because the absolute value of its derivative is bounded by $\sin(1) < 1$ on that interval.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  I would like to accept your answer .But I can't justify your claim $a_n \in [a_2 ,1]$ for $n\ge 3$ since you are using the contractiveness there only. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: @user710290 I updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the Edelstein's version of the Banach fixed point theorem: if $X$ is a complete, **compact** metric space and a continuous $f:X\to X$ is such that $|f(x)-f(y)|< |x-y|$ holds for any $x\neq y$, then $f^{(n)}(x)$ converges to a fixed point of $f$.

In your case you may take $X=[-1,1]$ since $a_2\in[-1,1]$ regardless of the value of $a_1$.

---

Proof of the theorem: let $\Phi(x)=d(x,f(x))$. $\Phi$ is a continuous function: let $z\in X$ and $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of elements of $X$ convergent to $z$. By the triangle inequality
$$ \Phi(x_n)\leq d(x_n,z)+d(z,f(z))+d(f(z),f(x_n)) $$
i.e.
$$ \Phi(x_n)-\Phi(z)\leq d(x_n,z)+d(f(x_n),f(z)) $$
where the RHS converges to zero as $n\to +\infty$, implying
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\Phi(x_n) = \Phi(z). $$
**Crucial part**: Since $X$ is compact, $\Phi$ has a minimum at some $y\in X$. Assuming $y\neq f(y)$ we have
$$ \Phi(f(y))=d(f(y),f(f(y)))<d(y,f(y))=\Phi(y) $$
contradicting the minimality. This gives that $y$ is a fixed point of $f$.
Such fixed point is unique: assuming that $x\neq y$ is a different fixed point,
$$ d(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y) $$
leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks sir. Just curious to know the proof. Is it possible to share it or at least give some hint?

Comment: @user710290: I have added the proof. It is not a really well-known version of the fixed point theorem, but it is a very useful one.

Comment: But (unless I am mistaken), $\cos$ is a strict contraction on $X=[-1,1]$, which means that you don't need this improved version.

Comment: @MartinR: of course you're right, but still this version might come handy if $f(x)$ is bounded but not regular as $\cos(x)$.

Comment: What paper of Caccioppoli has this version of the Banach fixed point theorem? I have known this result as a theorem of Edelstein from 1962 ("On fixed and periodic points under contractive mappings", J. London Math. Soc.)

Comment: @KCd: the only paper I have not been able to check and may contain the version   described by Jack is R. CACCIOPPOLI, Un teorema generale sull’esistenza di elementi uniti in una trasformazione funzionale, Rend. Acc. Naz. Lincei, s. VI, 11 (1930), 357-363.

Answer (score 1):

You needn't worry too much. As the figure shows, past the first one, the function iterates (order blue, magenta, green, black) remain in $[\cos1,1]$ where the absolute slope of the cosine is below $1$.

[image]