# Edelstein's Version of the Banach Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

My question is in the context of this answer.(https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3774433/710290). Please read this answer before getting to my question.

The statement of the theorem is

If $X$ is a complete, compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ is continous and satisfies $d(f(x),f(y))\lt d(x,y)$ for $x\neq y$ then the recursive sequence $f^{(n)}(x)$ is convergent.

Now, in the context of the answer, I have understood that $f$ has a unique fixed point but I can't understand what makes the recursive sequence convergent in the first place at all?

My thinking :

Let $\{a_n\}$ be the recursive sequence where $a_1=x$ and $a_{n+1}=f(a_n) ,\forall n\in 
 \mathbb{N}$. Then since the space $X$ is compact , there is a convergent subsequence $\{a_{r_n}\}$ .

Let $a_{r_n} \to l$ as $n\to \infty$.

Then $a_{r_n+1}=f(a_{r_n})\to f(l)$ as $n\to \infty$ by the continuity of $f$.

Similarly $a_{r_n+2}=f(a_{r_n+1})\to f(f(l))$ as $n\to \infty$

Similarly, for $k\in \mathbb{N}$

$a_{r_n+k}\to f^{(k)}(l)$ as $n\to \infty$

But I don't understand what to conclude from this. Please help.

As a sidenote, before you ask the question why didn't I ask there in the comments , I want to make it clear that I asked it there but didn't get any reply. So I thought of posting this as a separate question.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: The space is compact and metric, so every infinite sequence has a convergent subsequence. The contraction-like property lets you extend it to the full sequence rather than just a subsequence. Does this help?

Comment: @Clayton  May be you are correct but I am not sure how to use your hint , sir.

Comment: It is spelled Caccioppoli, with double *p*. ;-)

Comment: A proof of this result is given as Theorem 3.5 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/contraction.pdf.

Comment: @KCd  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the aforementioned [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3774433/710290) in the OP, it is proven that $f$ has a unique fixed point, say $w$.

---

To show that for any $x\in X$, $f^{(n)}(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}w$, we show that any subsequence of $\{f^{(n)}(x)\}$ admits a subsequence that converges to $w$.

---

Following the notation of the link, define the function  $Q(x):=d(f(x),x)$. Since $f$ continuous, so is $Q$;  moreover, unless $x$ is a fixed point of $f$, we have that   $$Q(f(x))=d(f(f(x)),f(x))<d(f(x),x)=Q(x)$$

If $Q(f^{(n)}(x))=0$ for some $n_0$, then $f^{(m)}(x)=f^{n_0}(x)$ for all $m\geq m_0$ and so, $f^{(n)}(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f^{(n_0)}(x)=w$ since  $f^{(n_0)}(x)=f(f^{(n_0-1)}(x))=f^{(n_0-1)}(x)$.

Suppose  $x$ such that $Q(f^{(n)}(x))>0$ for all $n$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
 Q(f^{(n)}(x))<Q(f^{(n-1)}(x))<\ldots<Q(x)\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}$$
and so,  $Q(f^{(n)}(x))$ converges. On the other hand, as $X$ is compact, any subsequence $\{f^{(n')}(x)\}$ of $\{f^{(n)}(x)\}$ admits a convergent subsequence $\{f^{(n_k)}(x)\}$. Say,
$$f^{(n_k)}(x)\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}y\in X$$

For any $n$, there is a unique $k$ such that $n_k\leq n<n_{k+1}$; hence
$$Q(f^{(n_{k+1})}(x))<Q(f^{(n)}(x))\leq Q(f^{(n_k)}(x))$$
and so, by the continuity of $Q$
$$\begin{align}
\lim_nQ(f^{(n)}(x))=Q(y).\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
$$
By $\eqref{zero}$,
$$Q(f^{(n)}(x))>Q(y),\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

We claim that $y$ is  a fixed point. Otherwise,  $Q(f(y))<Q(y)$. However, $Q(f(y))=\lim_k Q(f(f^{(n_k)}(x))\geq Q(y)$ which is a contradiction; hence $y$ is a fixed point, and by uniqueness $y=w$.

We have shown that any subsequence of $\{f^{(n)}(x)\}$ admits a subsequence that converges to the unique fixed point $w$ of $f$. From this, we conclude that in fact $f^{(n)}(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}w$.

---

Edit: This is to address a comment from the OP:

**Lemma:** Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $a\in X$ and $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset X$. The sequence $a_n$ converges to $a$ iff any subsequence $a_{n'}$ of $a_n$ admits a subsequence $a_{n''}$ that converges to $a$.

Here is a short proof:

($\Longrightarrow$) Obvious.

($\Longleftarrow$) Suppose $a_n$ does not converge to $a$. Then, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, there is $n_k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(a_{n_k},a)\geq \varepsilon$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $n_k<n_{k+1}$. Then $\{a_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and no subsequence of $\{a_{n_k}\}$ converges to $a$ (for $d(a_{n_k},a)\geq\varepsilon$ for all $k$).

Comment: Thanks sir. I have some questions/confusions. Please clarify these before I accept the answer. $(1)$ Why did you prove the result via subseqence of a subsequence ? I mean you could have started " Since the space $X$ is compact, there is a convergent subsequence of $\{f^{(n)}(x)\}$ ". and then rest of the work.                    $(2)$ Also in the last paragraph , are you trying to say "If for a sequence $\{a_n\}$ , if it happens that any subsequence of it admits a subsequence that converges at a particular point $a$ (say) , then the original sequence  $\{a_n\}$ converges to $a$. ?

Comment: @user710290: (1) originally, I had taken a convergent subsequence of $f^{(n)}(x)$. But I quickly realized that by considering subsequences from the beginning avoids repetition of arguments. Thus,  I change the strategy slightly and based it on the fact that (2)  if a sequence $A=\{a_n\}$ (in a metric space) is such that for some $a$ any subsequence $a_{n'}$ of  $A$ admits a convergent subsequence $a_{n''}$ with limit $a$, then necessarily $a_n$ converges to $a$. If  that fact I not clear to you, I can write a short proof.

Comment: Great , really appreciate your help. Everything's clear now . Thanks again.